# Why unseting a var from a class have inconsistent resuls

Tags: php, class, set, unset, magic-methods

A few days ago I took a while to debug an issue, and found out the weird behaviour from unset() class vars and magic __set() method.

So here is the thing:

```
class A {
    public $var;

    public function unsetVar() {unset($this->var);}
}

class B extends A {
    public $attr = array();
    public function __set($key, $value) {$this->attr[$key] = $value;}
}

$a = new A();
$a->unsetVar();
$a->var = 'teste';

$b1 = new B();
$b1->var = 'teste';

$b2 = new B();
$b2->unsetVar();
$b2->var = 'teste';

var_dump($a, $b1, $b2);
```

php online example: http://goo.gl/CO3Uxj

That var_dump() returns:

```
object(A)#1 (1) {
  ["var"]=>
  string(5) "teste"
}
object(B)#2 (1) {
  ["attr"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["var"]=>
    string(5) "teste"
  }
}
```

So if unset the $a->var then the re-set will work as expected, just to be sure $b1->var will set the var and not triggering the magic method, but when at b2 we unset the var, then the magic method will be triggered not resetting the $b2->var.

Firstly I thought that internally PHP would use the magic method __set() to set the vars that were unset by using reflection or some internal method to check the property exist.

So since I've overridden __set() it would execute mine, but didn't found nothing to support this.

So, does anyone know why it behaves like this? 
(with some docs to support)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Because `unset` destroys the variable, thus removing the property from the class. Basically `__set` gets called if `isset(prop)` returns FALSE, and if you have called `unset(prop)`, then `isset(prop)` must be false (since you just unset it). This is my own interpretation from docs for the mentioned functions. I didn't see this clearly stated anywhere in the docs.

Comment: Tested it, and before setting the var, isset() will return false, so if that is equivalent to be unset, the __set() call should also be called even if the unset() wasn't, which doesn't make much sense... 
php it's weird :P

Comment: That's a good point, and I was wrong. See my answer. I gave it some more thought, ran more tests and read more docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset($var)` destroys the variable `$var`, making it inaccessible, causing a 'undefined variable' notice if you try to use `$var` again. To clarify `unset()` destroys the `variable`, not the `value`. and destroying the variable means that it would no longer exist (be accessible).

I couldn't find docs clearly stating this, but the following test supports my claim (as does your test with `__set`).

I did the following which demonstrates that `__unset()` actually makes variables inaccessible:

```
class x {
    public $var;
}
$x = new x();
  echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_object_vars($x)); //prints Array([var] =>)
      echo '<br>';
unset($x->var); //prints Array()
print_r(get_object_vars($x));
```

So, `get_object_vars` docs state:

> Gets the accessible non-static properties of the given object according to scope.

and `__set`, docs state:

> is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.

and `unset()`, docs state:

> destroys the specified variables

From which I conclude 'destroys' = 'make variable inaccessible' because if `unset` had done anything other than make it inaccessible, then `[var] =>` (or `[var] =>NULL`) would have been printed the 2nd time.

To answer your question.

> So, does anyone know why it behaves like this? (with some docs to support)

Because it is supposed to. The docs just don't clearly state how it functions on class variables.

Also (docs needed), class variables are references to values, and unsetting a reference destroys just the reference not the value (unless it is the only reference to the value).

**Edit:** You could possibly [report a documentation bug](https://bugs.php.net/report.php?bug_type=Documentation+problem&manpage=function.unset) if you're not satisfied with this answer.

Comment: It's not the first case where php acts weird... Marked your answer as correct. However reading this made me wonder what should be the best way to under (clear from memory)  the variables

Comment: @XicoXperto, `unset` does a perfect job of clearing memory of variables. If you have `$a = 'str'; $b = $a; unset($b); unset($a);`, and you check mem usage before and after, it should be identical (i tested it a few days ago). Also, when the `unset($a)` is called, a larger chunk of memory is freed (compared to the `unset($b)` call) because it removes 'str' from memory, whereas the first unset (`unset($b)`) only removes a reference to 'str', since `$a` is still pointing to it.